# Regex for excluding a character

Tags: regex

I am using `=@.*?@` to find placeholders in a string e.g: `=@something@`.
Now i want to forbid any `=` in between the 2 `@`. So that this String is not found: `=@some=@any@@`.

Comment: Why should `=@any@` not be found in the second string?

Comment: Because with current setup `=@.*?@` would find `=@some=@` which would destroy the inner placeholder on replacing.

Comment: Sure, but with your new setup it won't find that match any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
=@[^=@]*@
```

Comment: nice :) and with `[^=@&/:?]*=@[^=@]*@` i can set left borders for the descriptions of my placeholders... thank you :)... ill be able to accept your answer in a few mins...